# Firebase not saving data from loop generated iOS data

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to fill in some data in my iOS Firebase database using a loop but it only seems to be saving the last value. Kinda stumped :/

```
while (counter < 50){
patientName = newPatient.patientName + String(counter)

    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("testTable").child("patient").setValue(patientName)
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("testTable").child("patient").child(patientName).child("patient DOB").setValue(newPatient.patientDOB)
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("testTable").child("patient").child(patientName).child("test var").setValue(newPatient.patienttest)
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("testTable").child("patient").child(patientName).child("test var 1").setValue(newPatient.patienttest1)
    counter += 1

}
```

And this is the output I see on on the console:

```
2017-01-31 09:48:25.999233 DemoTest[15969:1332318] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash simulate crash already simulated "nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available"
2017-01-31 09:48:25.999827 DemoTest[15969:1332318] [] nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available, dumping backtrace:
```

The database just adds/saves the last value:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Essentially I was overwriting my entries, what I should have put instead was just simply .child(patientName) and then for the rest I can do setValue.  This is all from the firebase documentation:

**Gets a FIRDatabaseReference for the location at the specified relative path. The relative path can either be a simple child key (e.g. ‘fred’) or a deeper slash-separated path (e.g. ‘fred/name/first’).**